# The source attachment does not contain the source for the file PApplet.class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, processing

I'm making a sound toy for Android using Android Processing. I first wrote the code in the Processing editor, but am now bringing it in to Eclipse to take advantage of a sound library called libpd. I tried to run the app on my phone, but got the following errors from the debug window:

```
Main(PApplet).die(String) line: 2451    
Main(PApplet).die(String, Exception) line: 2460 
Main(PApplet).loadFont(String) line: 3625   
Main.setup() line: 62   
Main(PApplet).handleDraw() line: 1779   
PGraphicsAndroid2D.requestDraw() line: 161  
Main(PApplet).run() line: 1670  
Thread.run() line: 1019
```

What confuses me is that one of the errors is about being unable to find a font file. I put all the necessary vector image files, and the font file in particular in the project's assets folder, so I'm not sure what is a happening there.

Mainly, the errors seem to be concerned that "the source attachment does not contain the source for the file PApplet.class". I have imported the processing.core.* to all of my classes, and the main class extends PApplet. In a similar project I do not get this error.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/HxQvk9y9) is the code of my main class, if you need me to clarify anything don't hesitate to ask. Sorry, the code is pretty ugly...

EDIT: [Here](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Android#Common_problems) is the link to the Android processing page.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I inadvertently added a space character in the name of the font file. It was named "HelveticaNeue-48.vlw ", which caused the slew of errors when I referred to it without the space.